# CloudFront - How to upload images

Tags: web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, cloud

I have 3 questions related to Amazon CloudFront.

1. How do I upload images?
2. Can I use FTP?
3. Does Amazon allow me to rsynch a local directory to CloudFront so that I have a replica directory and hierarchy on CloudFront?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can use CloudBerry Explorer freeware to upload images to Amazon S3 and configure CloudFront. Please check out our blog post on how to do that. http://blog.cloudberrylab.com/2009/04/how-to-host-media-files-on-amazon-s3.html

Answer (score 2):

1. I've found [bucket explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/) to work well on trial, not sure yet if it's worth $50
2. Pretty sure you can't
3. Haven't tried but bucket explorer blurb says "Synchronize local and Amazon S3 data using comparer."

Answer (score 1):

You upload files to Cloudfront by uploading them to S3. You can upload to S3 via the REST interface. There is no FTP support. There are numerous software packages and code libraries to handle uploading if you don't want to write your own.

If there was a rsync client that supported uploading to S3, then yes you could use rsync. I am not familiar with any.

Comment: You'd probably use S3FS (http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) to sync with rsync. I didn't find S3FS quite stable enough to use on a daily basis all though it does have some potential.

Comment: CloudFront actually supports uploading to the cloudfront edge node too -- see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudfront-content-uploads-post-put-other-methods/ (that is as of 2013 so things might have changed since the original reply in 2009 -- just commenting for those ending up here today)

Answer (score 1):

There's a Firefox add-on that feels a lot like FTP http://www.s3fox.net